# How to gain access to if statement checked value ? in side the if block?

Tags: javascript

How to gain access to if statement checked value (case), inside the if block after the check happend ? instead of having to write another 4 conditional according to each case ?

```js
if ((obj.a === '' || obj.b === '' || obj.c === '' || obj.d === '')) {
      console.log(what case has been triggered ?)
      selected.a ? something : null
      selected.b ? something : null
      selected.c ? something : null
      selected.d ? something : null
    }
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to change global context in react according to each case.. but I want a more elegant way ? instead of having to check again for each condition so I want to know what of the above did get triggered !

Comment: @NoxinDVictus the prams are just  a speculation for what might be passed downs from the check block ! if anything like this even exist, or is checking again my only option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an object that contains the result of each of a comparisons in a object with the corresponding keys using `Array.reduce`:

```
const obj = { a: " ", b: " ", c: " ", d: " " };

const boolObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce((accum, key) => {
    accum[key] = obj[key] === " ";
    return accum;
}, {}); // result: {a: true, b: true, c: true, d: true}
```

Then, you can check for validity using `Array.every`:

```
if (Object.values(boolObj).every(val => val)) {
    // do something
}
```

However, since you did not provide some better context, I cannot give a better answer that fits your needs. To me, I think this is over-engineering, and I'm quite sure there probably are much better ways of solving the problem relative to your context.